# VSCode の復帰後、突然 '__ 2.js' という名前のファイルが作成されました

Tags: docker, vscode

VSCode での作業中に「ファイル名 2.js」といったバックアップのファイルが作成されました。
原因がわかる人がいたら教えて欲しいです！

1. VSCode で react.js + ruby のwebアプリを作成中
2. パソコンの電池の残量がなくなりスリープモードに
3. 再び電源をつける
4. 既存のjsの複製のようなものが作成される

   task.js → task 2.js
   Form.js → Form 2.js

ちなみに今回コミットしていなかった分は `task 2.js` に残っており、`task.js` は最新コミットの状態に戻りました。

今までに２度同じようなことがありました。
ローカル環境はDockerで作成しています。

もし何が起きたのかわかる方がいればご教授いただけますと幸いです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 復帰・再開時に以前の未セーブの作業ファイルが別名で保存された感じですが、それを行うような設定または拡張機能が使われていませんか？

Comment: hinaloeさん、ご回答ありがとうございます！特にそういう拡張機能は利用していないのですが、おっしゃる通り知らずのうちに利用しているかもしれません。。再度利用している機能を洗い出してみようと思います。